# Как скачать через JS сформированный файл php

Tags: javascript, php

у меня создается на сервере файл c помощью php скрипта:

```
$file = 'Реестр от '.date('Y-m-d H-i-s').'.xlsx';

// Если пользователь работает в IE 9, то может потребоваться следующее
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($file);
//редирект на сохранение
$file = basename($_GET['file']);
if(!file_exists($file)){ // file does not exist
    die('file not found');
} else {
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
}
```

Я вызываю скрипт с помощью JS  вот так

```
function save(){ // кнопка Скачать

        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        let par = url.searchParams.get('objID'); // => value
        $.ajax({
            url: "export_excel.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"objID": par},
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу после формирования файла его скачать?

Comment: Так же обратись запросом на некий УРЛ - сервер пусть тебе вернет этот файл. Если сервер его запишет в папку со "статикой" - тебе достаточно знать УРЛ "до" этого файла.

Comment: Если это чисто ПХП-шный вопрос - вот про такое статья https://habr.com/ru/articles/151795/